# Delete a lot of records of SageMaker Feature Store

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, feature-store, aws-feature-store

I want to keep the **OfflineStore**, but I want to change the `is_deleted` column and hide than at **OnlineStore**. I know that in situations where I want to delete a record, I could use [delete_record](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker-featurestore-runtime.html#SageMakerFeatureStoreRuntime.Client.delete_record), but my question is: How to do it to many records in a scalable way?

Comment: Please clarify the requirements, stating the desired results in both the online and offline store.

Comment: @MarcKarp I wanted the Offline Store to keep the record, removing only for Online Store. So I could get the advantages of the time travel feature.

Comment: The online store will only contain the latest feature values. Batch deletion of historical features can be done directly on the offline store. Either by updating column is_deleted value or deleting the features entirely from S3.